# How to display array elements?

Tags: java, arrays

So I am trying to write a method that populate a board in a game. I am just beginning to learn about programming so I do not know much about special methods.

```
public static void Board(char[][] array){

  for(int i=0; i<2*array.length+1; i++) {
  if(i %2 ==0){
    for(int j=0; j<2*array.length+1;j++){
      if(j%2==0){
        System.out.print("+");
      }
      else{
        System.out.print("-");
      }
    }
  }
  else {
      for(int j=0; j<2*array.length+1;j++){
        if(j%2==0){
          System.out.print("|");
        }
        else{
          System.out.print(" "); // Maybe should use this spot to insert the x and o from the array.
        }
  }
    }
  System.out.println();
```

But in the board, where I currently have empty spaces, I want to actually be able to accept input.

For example , if

```
char [][] b={{'',' x',' ',},{' ','s','t '},{'o','o',' '}};
 Board(a);
```

Then instead of only having the empty spaces, I would like the element corresponding to the array to go there. I marked on my code where I think this might be done. I don't know of any special methods, but possibly *DeepArray* to string or such.
I understand how to import using Arrays.ToString, the issue is with the index.

Comment: If your goal is to provide custom formatting, please detail how you want the output to look.  Otherwise it's really hard to guess from your code.

Comment: You're almost there. Replace `print(" ")` with `print(array[i/2][j/2])`.

Comment: While I'm sure Andreas is correct, your code is completely insane at this point.  Even though you might see twice as many characters on a line as array elements, the **index** of the array should never use `x<2*array.length+1`.  Just use the normal number of elements in the array, *don't* divide by 2 as suggested, and your code will look a lot cleaner and be easier to understand (esp. for you).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045604/how-to-display-array-elements/47045849#comment81038735_47045604), you're almost there:
Replace `print(" ")` with `print(array[i/2][j/2])`.

That will then make the code print correct output, after also fixing the errors in the two lines of code calling the method:

```
char[][] b={{' ','x',' '},
            {' ','s','t'},
            {'o','o',' '}};
Board(b);
```

*Output*

```
+-+-+-+
| |x| |
+-+-+-+
| |s|t|
+-+-+-+
|o|o| |
+-+-+-+
```

To followup on [comment by @markspace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47045604/how-to-display-array-elements#comment81038841_47045604), your code can be simplified like this:

```
public static void printBoard(char[][] board) {
    StringBuilder line = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < board[0].length; i++)
        line.append("+-");
    String rowSeparatorLine = line.append('+').toString();
    System.out.println(rowSeparatorLine);
    for (char[] row : board) {
        line.setLength(0); // clear
        for (char cell : row)
            line.append('|').append(cell);
        System.out.println(line.append('|').toString());
        System.out.println(rowSeparatorLine);
    }
}
```

The code uses a [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) to build a whole line in memory before printing it, e.g. so it only has to build the row separator line once.

It also uses enhanced `for` loops to keep the code simpler.

I also fixed the method name. Java naming convention is for method names to start with lowercase letter, and should usually start with a verb, since the method is actually intended to *do* something.